# change label with ajax from controller?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, label

Hi everybody I need to change text label from JsonResult on my Controller... I have two problems...

- 1) I can't print on my view the text that I send from my
  controller...
- 2) I want to send 3 labels from my controller when I selected a
  option from my dropdownlist.

  Please help if someone know how to do this... :)

**On my View**

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label id="lblCargo"></label>
</div>

@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#ddlEmpleado").change(function () {
            var selectedItemValue = $(this).find(":selected").val()

            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("getLabels", "AsignarBien")',
                data: {
                    "id": selectedItemValue,
                },
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                Success: function() {
                    $("#lblCargo").text(data);
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("error");
                }
                }
            );
        });

    });
</script>
}
```

**On my Controller I got this**

```
public JsonResult getLabels(Guid id)
{
    var result = (from item in vempleados.GetAll().ToList()
        where item.IdEmpleado == id
        select item.Cargo).SingleOrDefault();

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: You need to have a data param in your success function. Also, is item.Cargo in your query an object or a string?

Comment: Yes you have to put something like this in your success  Success: function(data) {
                    $("#lblCargo").text(data);
                },

Comment: If you are returning a JSON object you have to iterate it, or acces to it by key, value.

Answer (score 1):

**Three small changes and it will work:**

1. `success` must be lower case.
2. Add the `data` parameter to the `success` function.
3. There should be no comma (`,`) after `selectedItemValue`

Basically make your `$.ajax` call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    url: '@Url.Action("getLabels", "AsignarBien")',
    data: { "id": selectedItemValue},
    success: function (data) {
        $("#lblCargo").text(data);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

**NOTE:You don't need to specify the contentType for the GET request, so you can take that out completely.**